# devise flash message being notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I'm working on setting up my flash messages. Currently my _messages looks like this:

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, message,  class: "alert alert-#{message_type}", role: "alert") %>
<% end %>
```

however with devise they keep on using alert-notice. Which via bootstrap obviously have no colors connected to it. How do I go about changing the devise default to one of the 4 selected?

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is that:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    <% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
      <% if type == "notice" %>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
      <% elsif type == "alert" %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <% else %>
        <div class='alert alert-<%= "#{type}" %>'>
      <% end %>
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <%= msg %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add some kind of explanation of what "that" is?

Comment: Devise use notice and alert, you convert notice to success for bootstrap and alert to danger, so you will have nice flash message in green/red. You can always use other bootstrap color, example here: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think devise allows you to customize, but you could override some of its methods. Checkout this GitHub issue for some examples: 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2282